# secure the ajax calls to server side functions

Tags: php, security, codeigniter

I have a codeigniter application in which i do most of the stuff by way of ajax calls. For instance lets take the account creation. There is a form with four fields, username, password, email and mobile.

```
frm = $("signupform").serializearray();
$.post(base_url + "/auth/ajaxlogin/", frm, function(data){
                if(data==="true") {
                    window.location.reload();
                } else {
                   $("#loginresult").show(); 
                }
            });
```

with this script i am taking care of sending the account details to the account creation method in the auth controller, creating the account and signing the user in. But im sure that this is highly vulnerable, say any user can write a malicious script to continuosly create accounts in their js console. So what is the best way to secure certain functionality like this.

Comment: Doesn't matter if its AJAX or standard POST submission, should have sanitization / protection in place to mitigate these types of account creation attacks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Ajax is irrelevant, as far as the server is concerned, an HTTP request is an HTTP request.

Use the normal approaches for defending against that kind of attack:

- Confirmed opt-in test sent to the email address
- Rate limiting
- Captcha (only if the above don't provide sufficient protection, they annoy people)

Answer (score 0):

Each page could write out a unique key, only valid for a short period of time which forms part of the submission. This key is only valid once and for only a few minutes and must be valid for a form submission to be used.  The key would be visible in the source of course, but as it's only valid once, it will prevent continuous account creation.

You could also minify and obsfucate your JS this will make it harder for malicious people to attack your site.

Comment: But it is possible to reverse the minification and obfuscating in a simple way.

Comment: Why even bother to reverse it? Just monitor the HTTP requests using something like Firebug.

Answer (score 0):

There are any number of ways you can implement security- but if you want to lock down individual user abuse, why not check the IP of incoming requests and block repeat ones coming from the same IP within say, X minutes? This wont be a fix all, but is an additional layer that can be added with other methodologies.